# Как проверять активность radiobutton в laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, phpmyadmin

У меня в верстке есть radiobutton (из bootstrap)

Social life

как мне в мне отправить в БД активный (выбранный checkbox)

Мой контроллер:

```
public function blogadd(Request $request) {
    
    $blog = new Blog();
    
    $blog->title = $request->input('title');
    $blog->discrip = $request->input('discrip');
    
    $blog->save();
    

    return view('admin.blog');
}
```

Comment: В самом `$reques` приходят данные о чекбоксе?

Comment: Логично что нет, т.к. я не вписывал ничего связанного о checkbox в контроллер, это и хочу узнать

Comment: просто не совсем понял вопрос. секунду

Comment: У меня в верстке есть radio button из bootstap, пользователь должен выбрать один из 3 и нажать отправить, тот чекбокс который он выбрал должен попасть в БД

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала в миграции добавим колонку для этого чекбокса

```
    Schema::table('my_table', function (Blueprint $table) {
      
      $table->boolean('check')->default('false');
      
    });
```

в форме добавим строчку

```
 <input type="checkbox" name = "check">
```

В контроллере добавим еще одну строчку для хранения.

```
 public function blogadd(Request $request) {

    $blog = new Blog();

    $blog->title = $request->input('title');
    $blog->discrip = $request->input('discrip');
    $blog->check = $request->get('check', false);

    $blog->save();


    return view('admin.blog');
  }
```

В модели `Blog` добавим каст на колонку с чекбоксом, который будет кастить строку в булевое значение

```
class Blog extends Model
{
  
  protected $table = 'me_table';
  
  protected $casts = [
    'check' => 'boolean'
  ];

}
```

Comment: Все отправляется, но в бд отправляется всегда только ложное значение, вне зависимости от выбранного чек бокса

Comment: выведите результат выполнения команды `dd($request)`

Comment: +request: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag {#44 ▼
    #parameters: array:4 [▼
      "_token" => "JjsvjgAWl61nvbU1I1tCl3dYTY8pBrvqmfo7IGm8"
      "title" => "123"
      "discrip" => "234"
      "exampleRadios" => "option1"
    ]
  }